# Parse String "[ "a", "b", "c" ]" to List of Strings in Java

Tags: java

Need to parse String to List of Strings in Java.

I'm getting this string from an external API and it comes with the type `application/json`. I just need a way to parse this String to a List to further process the response.

"[ "a", "b", "c" ]" -> Java List of Strings containing elements "a", "b" and "c".

"[]" -> Empty String List

Comment: @blurfus No That's not what I'm looking for. I need to parse a string to a list

Comment: @Pshemo it is a response from an external API

Comment: downvoting for unclarity - in the comments under one of the answers the OP himself asks whether JSON library should not be used, but the question states nothing about JSON ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
 List<String> items = Arrays.asList(str.replaceAll("[\\[\\] \" ]", "" ).split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if it's already written in an `array` format in your `string`, it can be easy parsed as `JSON` using a JSON parser.

For example you can easily parse it with [**GSON** parser](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/module-summary.html) by writing something like:

```
List<String> list = new Gson().fromJson(yourJsonString, new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType());
```